# Literature comparison table in Miktex using TexStudio

Tags: tables, miktex, comparison

How do I remove the horizontal 1st-row border, and secondly, how do I make the horizontal line borders bold?
Also, any suggestion on moving the caption on the left and changing it in bold with some space between the table and the caption above would be the proper way to do it in scientific reports. Maybe something similar to this format style [image]... of course, color doesn't matter!

I also get an error if I use `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}` to scale the table to the text width.
The code is as follows:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
        \caption{Literature Review}
        \label{tab:my-table}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
                \hline
                \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
                \textbf{Nr.} &
                \textbf{Study} &
                \textbf{Study Purpose} &
                \textbf{Methodology} &
                \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Enviornmental Scale \\ \& Sample size\end{tabular}} &
                \textbf{Key Findings} &
                \textbf{Concolusions} \\ \hline
                &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}%
        }
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output result without scaling the table to text width:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You have no caption in your code. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Bernard, what do you mean if that is international?

Comment: I wrote *intentional*. Furthermore, It's not clear how to make a link between the posted image and the result of your code.

Comment: Oh, sorry, My mistake, I misread it. Anyways The picture is the result I want to achieve and is not the outcome of the code. Now I have edited my query according to my new attempt at what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Never use `\resizebox` for tables: it leads to inconsistent font sizes. Better use `tabularx` since you fix  the overall table width. B.t.w., do you want the caption at the left side or centred w.r.t. the table?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand about using `tabularx` instead of `\resizebox`. If I put it in my code as `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{%` then further content, it gives me an error of **no position in optional float specifier**.
I want the caption on the left side.

Answer (score 2):

I have posted the new code.  Regard row borders, it doesn't matter, as I had resolved in the previous code that I had posted earlier. The column's head with a long name doesn't show its full text (i.e., **Environmental scale & sample size**). I tried changing the column width, but it remains the same. Also, as you see from the picture in each column and row (each cell), the text length will vary, and in some cells, I intend to add a list or bullets inside the cell. The table is long. I want it role to next page with the same head and with foot saying "continuous to next page," But I don't know how to use `\usepackage{longtable}` inside the `tabularx` package unless there is a way to do it within `tabular package.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, caption, makecell, booktabs,enumitem}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries\scriptsize}
\renewcommand{\theadalign}{bc}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, font=small, labelfont=bf}
    \caption{Literature Review}
    \label{tab:my-table}
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt}
    \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
    \rowcolors{1}{Gainsboro}{}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{3}{>{\hsize=0.95\hsize}X}>{\hsize=1\hsize}X*{3}{>{\hsize=0.95\hsize}X}}
    \noalign{\vspace*{-2ex}} \toprule
    \thead[l]{Nr.} &
    \thead{Study} &
    \thead{Study's Purpose} &
    \thead{Methodology} &
    \thead{Environmental Scale \\ \& Sample size} &
    \thead{Key Findings} &
    \thead{Conclusions} \\ \midrule 
    
    1 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  \\
    
    2 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
    
    3 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\ 
    4 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
    
    5 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & 
         \begin{itemize}
            \item 1st bla bla bla bla
            \item  2nd bla bla bla bla ba bla bla
        \end{itemize} \\
    
    6 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\ 
    
    7 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
    
    8 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
    
    9 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  \\
    
    10 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  \\
    
    11 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  \\ 
    
    12 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  \\ 
    
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, the `tabulkarx` part seems way complicated and out of my understanding, at least for now— **[** It would be nice to explain the `tabularx` what does what **]**. Anyways, Once again, thank you very much! – 2ndly, I changed the code to alternate the row color and added `\toprule` & `bottomrule` in the beginning and ending of my rows. Doing so, I get weird free space above and below, any solution for that?

Comment: I tried using this code after `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt}`. It does the trick, but it changes the borderline of each row fat and thin.

`\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}`

`\addtolength{\extrarowheight}{\aboverulesep}`

`\addtolength{\extrarowheight}{\belowrulesep}`

`\renewcommand{\aboverulesep}{0pt}`

`\renewcommand{\belowrulesep}{0pt}`

Comment: Also, from your code, How do I remove the borders from the 1st heading row keeping the background color only?

Comment: Do you mean the horizontal lines at the top and bottom of the heading row?

Comment: Yes, the borderlines of the horizontal heading row.

Comment: Let me explain the use of `tabularx` here: I introduced 5 X columns, which will have all the same width. However, the third of these X columns has a heading wider than the others. So  I decided to use the possibility to modulate the widths of these X columns, with the construct `>{\hsize= some_coefficient·\hsize}X`. These coefficients behave as barycentric coefficients in geometry: each is proportional to the length of the X column with this coefficient, the condition being that their sum is equal to the total number of  X columns (note that $4×0.95+1.20=5). Am I clear?

Comment: @FRQ: I've posted a simplified version of the code for the alternating row colours. Your problem with row boreders is not clear to me. Do you want to remove these lines for the heading row, for all rows or keep only a top and a bottom rule?

Comment: Thank you. I have posted the code again with some  minor changes and result, but I don't know how to handle the table if it goes beyond one page, other problem mentioned in the text above

Comment: If the table is longer tan one page, load `xltabular` package, which brings the functionalities of  `longtable` to `tabularx`, and replace  the `tabularx`environment with `xltabular`. Note that the latter environment uses the longtable syntax for caption (incorporated to  the environment).