# Table that may go to more than 1 pages

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, landscape, vertical

I have done many changes from the very beginning till the end and then with the help of [another person here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/592119)

I have achieved the result that I wish, let's say more or less. In trial and error, I got one thing corrected; the other got wrong. Long story short, I need your suggestions and help in achieving

> What do I need to change that *column* **study** or perhaps the text below aligned with the header name **study** (left or right) or vice versa as in the header is left intended like all others?

> How can I avoid a long table like that overlaps on the page numbers and moves continuously down without respecting the page size?

> Is there any way to put the numbered list or bulleted list in a random cell without disturbing the whole format, style, or dimensions?

> Also, will this code make problem if chnaged to Landscape page layout?

*without Altered colored rows is also acceptable but a nice top and bottom rule is giving me hell lot of headache*

[image]

```
\documentclass[svgnames, table]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx, caption, makecell}

\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries\scriptsize}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[!ht]
        \setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
        \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, font=small}
        \caption{\textbf{Literature Review}}
        \centering
        \label{tab:my-table}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
        \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{3}{>{\hsize=1\hsize}X}>{\hsize=1\hsize}X*{3}{>{\hsize=1\hsize}X}} 
            \noalign{\vspace*{-2ex}} \toprule
            \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
            \thead{Nr.} &
            \thead{Study} &
            \thead{Study's Purpose} &
            \thead{Methodology} &
            \thead{Environmental Scale\\ \& Sample size} &
            \thead{Key Findings} &
            \thead{Conclusions} \\ 
            1 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  \\ 
            \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
            2 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\ \midrule
            3 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\ 
            \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
            4 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\ \midrule
            5 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\ 
            \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
            6 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\ \midrule
            7 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\ 
            \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
            8 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\ \midrule
            9 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  \\ 
            \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
            10 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  \\ \midrule
            11 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  \\ 
            \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
            12 & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  \\ \midrule
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}%
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want your table to occupy multiple pages, take a look at the `longtable` package (or at the `xltabular` package if you want to keep the `X` type columns you currently use).

Comment: Regarding "put the numbered list or bulleted list in a random cell without disturbing the whole format": I currently see neither numbered nor bulleted lists in your code. What did you try so far to get them and what exactly changed? For `itemize` and `enumerate`-like lists inside of table cells that don't take up too much space, you might be interested in something like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/586735/134144

Comment: Regarding the alignment of column headers with respect to the text in the columns: `\thead` by default horizontally centers its contents. To override that, use its optional argument:  `\thead[l]{Study}` should give you the expected left aligned column header.